# VueJs Conditional handlebars

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

I'm trying to use VueJs conditional rendering using handlebars in vueJs 2.0 as per [their documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) but eslint is coming back with and error:

```
- avoid using JavaScript keyword as property name: "if" in expression {{#if ok}}
- avoid using JavaScript keyword as property name: "if" in expression {{/if}}
```

VueJs does not seem to be rendering it.

```
<!-- Handlebars template -->
{{#if ok}}
  <h1>Yes</h1>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to use Vue.js syntax, the documentation outlines just a few lines down what's done for Vue.js. You would use the `v-if` directive.

```
<h1 v-if="ok">Yes</h1>
```

If like you mentioned, you're wanting to use Handlebars alongside Vue.js, note that both of them use the same `{{` curly braces in templates. You may need to change Vue's use of the curly braces like so...

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['<%', '%>'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Either:

Using v-if to conditionally render

```
<h1 v-if="isVisible"> Yes </h1>
```

or using v-show to add a hidden attribute to that element style

```
<h1 v-show="isVisible"> Yes </h1>
```

either can be used but be careful with v-if since the element won't be in the DOM if the condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is simply to document that the conditional does not go on a parent tag, but rather it is placed directly on the node that you want to conditionally display.

In other words its simply a comparison not part of Vue.js markup, but rather part of Handlebars.

Comment: This might be better suited as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Vue conditional rendering syntax

```
<h1 v-if="ok">Yes</h1>
<h1 v-show="ok">Yes</h1>
```

Details in original docs.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You should look at the vue documentation .https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-showjs and by the way, you can use "v-if" and "v-show"attributes, in flowing related to
examples.

```
<h1 v-if='isShow'>Test</h1>
<h1 v-show='isShow'>Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here from a search trying to conditionally render inside `{{ }}` braces, you could always use a [computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) property:

```js
import { computed } from 'vue';

<script setup>
  const submitButtonText = computed(() => {
      return props.formObject ? 'Save' : 'Create';
  });
</script>

<template>
  <form>
    <button type="submit">
      {{ submitButtonText }}
    </button>
  </form>
</template>
```

`v-if` and `v-if-else` work perfect for large elements, but this is great for simple one-line conditional text.