# Conditional rendering of another element or parent in vuejs only if data available

Tags: javascript, vue.js

##Question

How should I add a conditional statement to my vue project to show a certain element if certain data is not available, and hide a parent.

##Background

I am getting data from a Taco API which includes a recipe. However sometimes that data is empty.

If there is data it currently looks like this

[image]

if there is no data, it just has a blank section

[image]

---

##Code

Demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/bjNmNM)

##HTML with vue

```
<h3>Recipe <span>not available</span></h3>
<p>
  <vue-markdown>{{ taco.recipe.title }}</vue-markdown>
</p>
<ul>
  <li v-for="item of taco.recipe.items">
    <vue-markdown>{{ item }}</vue-markdown>
  </li>
</ul>
```

###JS

```
data:{
  taco: { 
    name: '',
    condiment_name: '',
    condiment_recipe_url: '',
    recipe: { 
      title: '',
      items: []
    }
  }
},
```

---

##Intent

If Recipe has a value

- Normally render

If recipe {{ item }} value is blank

- The show the `<span>` in the title that says "not available".
- Do not render the parent `<ul>`
- Hide the paragraph above which takes in part of the value of {{ item }}

---

No solution from similar question [vuejs-conditional-handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558689/vuejs-conditional-handlebars).

I looked the [official documentation on conditionals](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) but I am unclear on how to implement it in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one below and use `v-if, v-else` condition, that should display `"no result"` when there is no result in the array.

```
<h3>Recipe <span>not available</span></h3>
<p>
  <vue-markdown>{{ taco.recipe.title }}</vue-markdown>
</p>

<div  v-if="taco.recipe.items.length > 0" > 
  <ul>
    <li  v-for="item of taco.recipe.items">
      <vue-markdown>{{ item }}</vue-markdown>
    </li> 
  </ul>
</div> 
<div v-else >
  No result found
</div>
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: This got me going in the right direction and I was able to figure it out from there. I wrapped everything in a `<section>` and just populated a different div based on if there was anything in the recipe.

Comment: I wonder if it would be a good idea to wrap certain things with this `v-if="taco.recipe.items.length > 0" >` namely the paragraph above, and the span in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example just introduce computed variable to see if its empty or not and use it to hide what u want.

```
 computed: {
    recipeNotEmpty: function () {
      return this.taco.recipe && this.taco.recipe.items.length > 0
    }
  },
...
<p v-if='recipeNotEmpty'>
      <vue-markdown>{{ taco.recipe.title }}</vue-markdown>
    </p>
    <ul v-if='recipeNotEmpty'>
      <li v-for="item of taco.recipe.items">
        <vue-markdown>{{ item }}</vue-markdown>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/aldarund/pen/GBpYwv)

Comment: probably `return this.taco.recipe && this.taco.recipe.items.length > 0` will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll be reusing it, you probably want a computed property that stores whether to show the recipe items. In your vue component configuration:

```
...
computed: {
  recipeItemsEmpty () {
    return this.taco.recipe && !this.taco.recipe.items.length
  }
}
...
```

With this, we can just use `v-if`s to render things conditionally:

```
<h3>Recipe <span v-if="recipeItemsEmpty">not available</span></h3>
<div v-if="!recipeItemsEmpty">
  <p>
    <vue-markdown>{{ taco.recipe.title }}</vue-markdown>
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item of taco.recipe.items">
      <vue-markdown>{{ item }}</vue-markdown>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that I added a div around your `p` and `ul` elments so the v-if condition could just be used once, but if you really don't want the div you can just put the same v-if condition on both the `p` and `ul` elements.

Comment: I'm sure this is the correct solution, but having a problem in my demo https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/RBaxLq

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me, every few times I click the button it shows the recipe, the other times it does not. Logging the taco object that gets returned, the times it doesn't show happen when the recipe seems to be a string instead of an object with items in it.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong I see your issue. I think I recall seeing something about vuejs and ajax stuff not playing nicely together... I can't quite remember though.

Comment: Also there was a small bug in my code, it should be `!this.taco.recipe.items.length` since it's supposed to represent being empty. Otherwise, I spent about an hour trying to fix the weird bug in your codepen, to no avail. I tried watchers instead of computed properties, I tried normal properties being set next to the taco property, I tried not using axios and instead using the vue-resources library, but none of them worked. I'm really not sure what the issue is, but I suspect it has something to do with the asynchronus nature of what you're doing, maybe try looking into async/vuejs stuff?

Comment: Wow that was super kind of you. yes the issue is that some times it will not display a new recipe. I will keep looking into this. I wish i could pay back your help somehow, or buy you some tacos lol.